# Imprimir elementos html en react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

necesito imprimir elementos html que son enviados por props en un componente en react. como lo hago. Puede ser con react.createelement?

Comment: Puede haber otra forma, si pudieras mostrar el código de lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Podría proporcionar más información?